# Checking if MDB is running

Tags: ejb, websphere-liberty

I have a EJB application deployed on WebSphere liberty. The application uses MDB for recieve messages from queue.

Is there any way I can check if the MDB is running/started on startup of application in code (other than by sending message to queue) ?

Answer (score 0):

During server startup in the `messages.log` look for similar messages:

```
[timestamp] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.ejbcontainer.runtime.AbstractEJBRuntime           I CNTR0180I: The beanName message-driven bean in the xyz module of the appNameapplication is bound to the as/myMDB activation specification.
[timestamp] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.sib.utils.ras.SibMessage I CWSIV0556I: Connection to the Messaging Engine was successful. The message-driven bean with activation specification as/myMDB will now be able to receive the messages from destination MyQueue.
[timestamp] 0000004b com.ibm.ws.jca.service.EndpointActivationService             I J2CA8801I: The message endpoint for activation specification as/myMDB and message driven bean application appName#beanName is activated.
```

I dont remember if it is presented in default logging settings (AUDIT) but I always change that to INFO like this:

```
    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" traceSpecification="*=info"/>
```